# Convertir PDF espanol con nombres para archivo de texto

Tags: linux, pdf, formato

Tengo un archivo PDF con miles de nombres. ¿Es posible extraer el contenido a un archivo de texto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respuesta rápida: Si.

No es necesario que uses el tag de "Linux", puesto que hay librerías en python, php, etc., que te pueden ayudar en esa labor. Incluso hay herramientas online como [esta](https://www.pdf2go.com/es/descargar/68749c78-1d5b-4620-92c0-4f75895aedd3). Pero supondré que quieres *escriptear* el asunto :)

Pero por preguntar para linux, hay herramientas como `pdftotext` del paquete `poppler-utils`.

Es decir, corre

```
$ sudo apt install poppler-utils
```

en tu terminal y luego puedes convertir un archivo pdf a texto con

```
$ pdftotext <tu archivo pdf>.pdf archivo.txt
```

Otra herramienta es `ebook-convert` del paquete `calibre`, es decir, instala el paquete con

```
$ sudo apt install calibre
```

y luego corres un comando semejante al anterior

```
$ ebook-convert <tu archivo pdf>.pdf archivo.txt
```

Aquí hay algunas comparativas que te pueden interesar.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/52040/is-there-a-better-pdf-to-text-converter-than-pdftotext

Lo que no he revisado bien es la parte que mencionaste de "español", quizás problemas como tildes, etc., si es que no te imprime bien esos caracteres, se puedan arreglar con la herramienta `iconv`. Igual puede que lo revise en momento y actualice mi respuesta.

Comment: `calibre` no funcionó pero con `orcmypdf`, una herramienta de python resolví mi problema. Después solo necesitaba la herramienta que me recomendó anteriormente, `pdftotext`, para extraer el texto en un archivo.

Comment: ¡Que bien! Pero ¿Por qué no te funciono `calibre`?